# How to get a string to contain one font for one part, and another font for part 2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring, nsmutableattributedstring

Essentially, I am trying to create a string that looks like this:

Already have an account? **Log in**

I have tried reading thru the documentation for `NSMutableAttributedString` but I cant seem to find the answer I am looking for.

So far, I have my `UIButton` setup as both an outlet to set the text, and an action.

Can someone please guide me thru the right steps?

Thanks

EDIT: I have both fonts i.e. (helvetica, helvetica bold) already added to my project... just need a way to differentiate between the two when using a single string to set the text for my button

Comment: Show what you have tried with regard to creating the attributed string with the desired setup.