# how do i find the range of a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

cant seem to be able to get it right..

I am trying to get the range of "Log in" but I just cant figure it out, this is what I am trying so far without result

```
NSString *alreadyHaveAccount = @"Already have an account? Log in";

const NSRange range = NSMakeRange(5, 7);
```

Comment: Don't you want `NSRange range = [alreadyHaveAcount rangeOfString:@"Log in"];`?

Comment: @rmaddy no I do, and that works..I am just trying to figure out myself, for my own benefit how to get ranges... i just can't wrap my head around them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998478/find-range-of-substring-of-string

Comment: so you want to know how to build your own implementation of searching substrings?

Comment: @vzm Your question is unclear. What exactly don't you understand? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The first argument is `start` and the second is `length`. So you probably want 25 and 6.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, yes correct

Comment: @rmaddy, I simply do not understand ranges. I would like to know how to figure out ranges. That is what I do not understand, I want to be able to tell ranges from A TO B by looking at the string.

Comment: A range is a starting point and a length. That's it.

Comment: Use the range because it is apple struct defined to perform task on string.With NSRange you can do more operation than only search. Read this link for more details: http://nshipster.com/nsrange/

Comment: @Rmaddy thank you, sorry for not being clear, but that is exactly what i wanted to know.

Comment: @jtbandes thank you, that is exactly what i wanted to know.

Comment: @vzm All you needed to do was read the docs for `NSRange`.

Comment: I think this question is related with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729244/how-to-get-a-string-to-contain-one-font-for-one-part-and-another-font-for-part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
NSRange range = [alreadyHaveAccount rangeOfString:@"Log in"];

if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"The string (alreadyHaveAccount) does not contain 'Log in' as a substring");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Found the range of the substring at (%d, %d)", range.location, range.location + range.length);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NSString` method `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString`.

In your case, the implementation would look like this.

```
NSString *alreadyHaveAccount = @"Already have an account? Log in";
NSRange rangeOfLogIn = [alreadyHaveAcount rangeOfString:@"Log in"];
```

Edit: If you wanted help creating your own method, you should have specified that.